# Spring integration: Event driven inbound channel adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to configure reading messages from Quickfix(Reads fix messages) into spring integration. I know I can use inbound-channel-adapter to read data from external source such as Quickfix. Can you provide an example of how to write an event driven inbound channel adapter?
I have following config which is not working

```
<bean id="QuickFixClient" class="com.limebrokerage.quickfix.QuickFixClient" >
<constructor-arg index="0" value= "/home/sbansal/workspace/bo/target/config/sterling.qfix" />
</bean>

<int:inbound-channel-adapter ref="QuickFixClient" method="fromApp" channel="FixChannel">
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: What issue do you have? Have you configured `<poller>` to poll that method periodically? Is that `path` really OK for the app? Does your `QuickFixClient` work if call it directly? Please, provide more info on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Message-driven channel adapters, typically, extend `MessageProducerSupport`, build a message using `MessageBuilder` and invoke `send(message)`.

Or you can write a simple POJO and inject a `<gateway/>` into it with a `service-interface` method that returns `void`.